# cannot import local module inside virtual environment from subfolder

Tags: python, pyenv, import-module

I am working inside a virtual environment created via `pyenv virtualenv` and my folder structure looks as follows

```
ProjectFolder (virtual env)
    Subfolder
        modulea.py
        __init__.py
    main.py
```

in the `main.py` I want to call a function defined in modulea.py. However,

```
from Subfolder.modulea import function
```

yields the error

> no module named Subfolder.modulea ; Subfolder is not a package.

when I reproduce an analog structure with some testfiles outside the virtual environments, all works well. Also, when I move `modulea.py` into the ProjectFolder the import works well.

Comment: Are you using an editor/IDE like vscode or pycharm?

Comment: I use emacs in general. However, the problem is the same when I execute the script in ipython in a the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

one possible work around is the following. in the directory `~/.pyenv/versions/your_virtual_environment/lib/your_python_version/site-packages`
add a file with extension `.pth` 
write the paths of all the Subfolder into this file, that contain modules that you would like to import.

`home/usr/Projects/Projectfolder/Subfolder/`

this adds the directory to the python PATH. Then, instead of importing via `from Subfolder.modulea import function` you can directly import import via `from modulea import function`. 
Alternatively adding the Subfolder to the Python Path via `sys.path.append` should before doing the import, should do the same job.

However, I am still puzzled why the usual "from... import... " syntax seems not to work inside the virtual environment.

Comment: That did not help in my case (using pyCharm IDE). Imported `pip install model_mommy` which worked, it placed the module in site-packages (venv/Lib/site-packages). Added a file `fixpath.pth` as suggested and put absolute path to site-packages inside that file. Still I cannot reference it (via `from model_mommy import mommy` as described in the [description](https://model-mommy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html#) of the module. What else can I do?